# Can we have multiple locations?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, location

I have two legal residences. One in the US (Baltimore) and one in The Philippines (Mandaluyong City). It's conceivable that I may start spending 1/3 of the year in Singapore as well.

I understand the recent fiddling with locations based on data returned from Yahoo, but I really want my profile to be accurate. It recently went from accurate to half accurate.

Would it be too much work to allow for multiple locations for the globe hopping minority, or should we just list the location that is our claim to citizenship? I thought about just updating my profile as my location changes, but I don't want to accidentally exclude myself from something that someone else is organizing based on a query.

Given the rest of the feature requests, I suppose this may seem trivial, but there's no harm in asking :)

Comment: You can still override the location in your profile to whatever you want

Comment: @random: such as 'Perpetual Agony'?

Comment: Some locations are near and dear to us all @alex

Answer (score 8):

I think that it's really too rare of a case that many users will need to list multiple entries for their location to be fully accurate. That's only my own take on it, though. I sometimes spend a good deal of the year halfway across the globe as well, but I'm not listing a legal residence as my location in the first place, haha.

The recent fiddling was one-time only, and is not enforced. Encouraged, perhaps, but not enforced. As such, I suggest that in the interrim period while this feature is evaluated, you just put your two/three locations inside that one field, perhaps separated by a semicolon. If you want, you can enter your locations individually, see how the Yahoo format specifies for each of them, and use those to stay in the same formatting.

You can either place your primary residence as the first entry, or the current one. I imagine that for studies, it would be more "accurate" that it is your current residence, but that requires you to update your profile. Sure, Copy makes it easier to push across the Network, but it's still an extra step, so the ball's in your court.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would actually be _worth_ it, but I tossed it out to see what everyone thinks. My feelings won't be hurt if it becomes status-declined.

Answer (score 2):

Now that the Data Explorer is updated on a pretty regular interval, you can just make sure you keep this field up to date if you tend to move about a bit and want to turn up in queries people run while organizing events and such.

And, well, this goes without saying - make sure you have some kind of contact means in your profile, or they'll find you to no avail :)

And really - OCD much do we?

Answer (score 1):

Your stackoverflow profile doesn't matter too much in this case.  You can put in multiple desired locations in your career's profile that will show employers where you are interested working.  If you must make this information more available, add it to your description.

Comment: I'm not overly concerned about my careers profile. I filled it out only to see what the 'over 100% completeness' thing was all about.